# nls() R-function works fine in R Studio but not in SQL Server 2016

Tags: r, stored-procedures, rstudio, sql-server-2016, nls

I am new to SQL Server with R Services and I am trying to implement a `nls()` function inside a Stored Procedure in order to find the best fitting curve that describes the data that the SP returns. The following nls() function with the specific arguments works properly in `R Studio` but, on the contrary, gives an error when trying to run it inside a stored procedure in the SQL Server. Keep in mind that the data-set that I am loading in `R Studio` is the same with the result of the Select statement that is used inside the stored procedure.

The stored procedure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (x NVARCHAR(MAX), y NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC    [dbo].[proc_ReturnDataForCurveGraphsDoubleNorm]
    @sRAWFILEID = N'5542', @PREBLEACHVALUES = 50, @BLEACHVALUES = 1, @INITIALBLEACHVALUES = 0

execute sp_execute_external_script    
   @language = N'R'   
  ,@script = N'
    df <- as.data.frame(c(InputDataSet));
    xdata <- df[,1];
    ydata <- df[,2];
    m = nls(y ~ yo - a*exp(-b*x), data = df, start = list(yo = 0.5, a = 0.563, b = 0.9), trace = F, control = list(maxiter = 1000), lower = list(0, 0, 0),upper = list(100, 100, 1), algorithm = "port");
    OutputDataSet <- data.frame(xdata, ydata);'    
   ,@input_data_1 = N' SELECT * FROM #TempTable;'  
    WITH RESULT SETS (([x] NVARCHAR(MAX), [y] NVARCHAR(MAX) ));
```

The error that I am getting:
`An external script error occurred: Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env, ifelse(internalPars <  : Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model`

The line of code that is executed properly in R Studio is the following:

```
m = nls(y ~ yo - a*exp(-b*x), data = df, start = list(yo = 0.5, a = 0.563, b = 0.9), trace = F, control = list(maxiter = 1000), lower = list(0, 0, 0),upper = list(100, 100, 1), algorithm = "port");
```

Also that's a flavor of the data (400 rows in total):

```
         x        y
1    2.692 0.163956
2    2.744 0.222050
3    2.795 0.261590
4    2.847 0.312176
5    2.898 0.335091
6    2.950 0.365475
7    3.002 0.389842
8    3.053 0.422475
9    3.105 0.446906
10   3.157 0.464013
11   3.209 0.479566
12   3.260 0.508908
13   3.312 0.503733
14   3.364 0.521298
15   3.416 0.538741
16   3.468 0.557562
17   3.520 0.562461
18   3.572 0.578120
19   3.624 0.607666
20   3.676 0.623594
21   3.728 0.625253
22   3.779 0.620704
23   3.831 0.629850
24   3.882 0.645155
25   3.934 0.660781
26   3.986 0.667858
27   4.038 0.685587
28   4.090 0.662437
29   4.142 0.672041
30   4.194 0.683506
31   4.245 0.708125
32   4.297 0.700848
33   4.349 0.692869
34   4.401 0.735460
35   4.453 0.715026
36   4.505 0.743622
37   4.557 0.728900
38   4.609 0.732680
39   4.661 0.737960
40   4.712 0.746198
41   4.764 0.752706
42   4.816 0.754294
43   4.867 0.772323
44   4.919 0.753392
45   4.970 0.776535
46   5.022 0.769763
47   5.074 0.793794
48   5.126 0.803506
49   5.177 0.803348
50   5.229 0.786406
....
....
380 22.362 0.936958
381 22.414 0.943523
382 22.466 0.945731
383 22.518 0.945423
384 22.570 0.924267
385 22.622 0.913668
386 22.674 0.938850
387 22.726 0.922154
388 22.778 0.927627
389 22.830 0.942964
390 22.882 0.941946
391 22.934 0.928719
392 22.986 0.954385
393 23.038 0.954852
394 23.089 0.937320
395 23.142 0.939765
396 23.194 0.936664
397 23.246 0.932192
398 23.297 0.931064
399 23.349 0.929592
400 23.402 0.936149
```

I am really wondering what's the problem in `SQL Server` that `R Studio` avoids.

Comment: Do you have an example of a working lm model via this approach?  I can't tell if problem is nls specific or the connection you have from sql to R. I doubt R Studio is avoiding any problem, you could run same code in R itself to see if R Studio makes a difference.

Comment: If I run the stored procedure without calling the nls function the script runs properly(actually the output of the select statement is returned). So doesn't this indicate that the connection between SQL Server and R is functional?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the comment. Can you do something simple in R inside the SQL code? After you have shown that then it may be something to do with nls specifically. Otherwise it's a problem with the SQL-R bridge syntax.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The problem is located in R engine inside SQL. I tried out with simple max() and min() functions and they both failed. Are there some standard steps I have to follow in order to figure out what's going on?

Comment: You might think about clarifying the title of your post and revising the problem statement.  You don't have a nls issue, so far as we can tell.  You have a more fundamental R <-> SQL question. I don't run R via SQL as you are trying to do, you probably are not attracting the attention of the correct user group by your title. Suggest something like "SQL Server R trouble: need basic help"

Answer (score 2):

SQL table (#TempTable) used as input_data_1 parameter in sp_execute_external_script is using NVARCHAR(max) data type for columns. `NVARCHAR` in SQL type maps to `character` type in R and dataframe would treat the strings as `factor` type by default. For passing data as numeric type to R you would need to use a corresponding SQL data type.

See [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) and [Working with R Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590948.aspx) for more information.